# Cluster-robust SE in Stata when using a survey design

Tags: stata, standard-error, survey, clustered-standard-errors

I'm working with data from a clustered sample where observations have a certain sampling weight (pweight). There are two ways to obtain the correct point estimates: I) using reg yvar xvar [pw = pweight] or ii) using svyset[pw = pweight] and then svy : reg yvar xvar These return identical point estimates (as they should). However, once one wants to introduce cluster-robust standard errors, the "manual" approach and the svyset approach return slightly different results. What I mean by "manual" is a command of the form: reg yvar xvar [pw = pweight], cluster(clustervar) as opposed to: svyset clustervar [pw = pweight] and then svy : reg yvar xvar. Here is a little code example to illustrate this with some numbers:

```
 sysuse auto
 set seed 92122
 *a variable containing random integers from 1 thru 4 designating fake clusters 
 gen mycluster = ceil(4*uniform())
 *random probability weights as the inverse of some random sampling probability
 gen mypw = 1/uniform()

 *run the "manual" regression
 reg price mpg weight [pw = mypw], cluster(mycluster)

 *using svy design
 svyset mycluster [pw = mypw]
 svy : reg price mpg weight
```

The standard errors are very close to one another but not identical (mpg is 72.48 and 71.48 and weight has 0.969 and 0.956). Stata calls the ones from the svyset-regression "Linearized" so I suppose that's where the difference comes from - potentially a Taylor expansion? Could somebody point me towards the precise (mathematical) difference? Are the patterns, i.e. one is always larger than the other?

I previously posted this question on Stackoverflow but it was deemed more appropriate here.

Comment: This was cross-posted to Statalist.  I quote the answer that I gave there http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1323537-cluster-robust-ses-with-survey-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard error for regress with a cluster() option will always be larger than that from svy: regress, with the ratio of squared standard errors equal to $\dfrac{n-1}{n-k}$, where  $n$ is the sample size and  $k$ is the number of predictors, including the intercept.

Here's a modification of your example to demonstrate this.  The change in definition of cluster should make no difference.

```
sysuse auto, clear
set seed 92122
gen mkr = substr(make,1,2)
codebook mkr // 23 clusters
*run the "manual" regression
reg price mpg weight [pw = gear], cluster(mkr)
scalar v1 = _se[mpg]^2
scalar k = e(rank) // number of predictors + 1
scalar n = e(N)

*using svy design
svyset mkr [pw = gear]
svy : reg price mpg weight
scalar v2 = _se[mpg]^2
di " v1 = " v1   "    v2 = " v2
di " n =  "n   "    k = " k
di " v1/v2 = "v1/v2
di " (n-1)/(n-k) = "(n-1)/(n-k)
```

The results of the display statements:

```
v1 = 5364.5846 v2 = 5217.6097
n = 74 k = 3
v1/v2 = 1.028169
(n-1)/(n-k) = 1.028169
```

The values in the last two lines are identical. Page 469 of the Stata 14 Manual entry for **_robust**,  (http://www.stata.com/manuals14/p_robust.pdf) refers to a multiplier $\dfrac{n}{n-k}$ that should make the two calculations equivalent. I verified the ratio $\dfrac{n-1}{n-k}$ in other examples. I can't account for the difference.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that make sense. Do you know why Stata would call the SE from the -svy- regression "linearized". Per your example, the difference is a simple ad-hoc adjustment for cluster size.

Comment: Not for cluster size but for number of clusters and number of predictors.

The standard error is called "linearized", because it's based on a first order Taylor expansion of the estimator about the true value.  Another name for this method is the "Delta" method. See Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method or http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/delta-method/

If you find the answer satisfactory, please "accept it".